# When does boost odeint actually call the observer?

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I am building a C++ class the uses boost::odeint to integrate a large biological simulation model. I am using the Runge-Kutta-4 stepper and an observer.

I understand that the observer is called at each time step, whereas the RK stepper calls the derivative function 4 times during each time step, and then calculates the final state from these 4 results.

I can't find anywhere in the documentation or on the internet, but is the observer is called

1. after the FOURTH of the 4 RK calls for each time step (at which point the derivative has not yet been calculated), or
2. after the FIRST of the 4 RK calls for each time step (at which point it has)?

Does any one know the answer to this?

I want to report the derivative from the observer, but I don't want to make an additional redundant call to the derivative function to do it.

Thanks

Comment: I notice that derivatives calculated in the FOURTH and subsequent FIRST function calls are almost identical. Which means the derivative is already available for the observer.

Comment: So the answer is: 1. after the FOURTH of the 4 RK calls. Although the calculated derivative at this point in time is not the final one, it seems to be very close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observer is called after (at the end of) each step, which means in general the derivative is not ready, specifically for RK4 the derivative is not yet computed.
If you worry about recomputing derivative, odeint allows to pass in the derivative into the low-level [do_step](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/5dd9519b7b603b7dd3d25d06900012405667426a/include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/base/explicit_stepper_base.hpp#L135) functions of the steppers - so you can compute and use the derivative outside and then pass it in. But this means you can't use the convenient integrate functions.

Comment: Ok, it's going to be very dependent on the internal logic of the stepper, isn't it. So in general we shouldn't assume anything about the sequence of function calls within the stepper. I suppose to be robust it's best to call the function from the observer if the correct rates are required to be returned. In my case the rate function is quite expensive unfortunately.

Comment: Using the smart steppers with step size and error control will probably save me more than I spend by calculating the rate in the observer.